# Sending SMS through USB interfaced GSM Modem in PHP

Tags: php, sms, gsm

I have searched on Google and found that I have to use AT commands to send SMS here is the link,

http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/

But in this tutorial he is using serial interfaced GSM modem, is it possible to send SMS via USB interfaced GMS modem. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A USB interfaced GSM modem will be presenting a USB serial interface, usually / hopefully conforming to the USB CDC specification. In other words you can treat it as a virtual COM port and the tutorial you linked to will still be relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix systems you can read/write from USB and Serial port reading data from /dev/ttyS0 or /dev/ttyUSB0. You also can use a usb/serial converter. They are cheap devices. But my experience with those usb converters is very bad. Because of that I prefer to use serial/ethernet convertes. They also allow me to place the serial device in any place and not necesary close to the server. OK maybe with a GSM device is not a problem. We can place it wherever we want, but if we are using the same technique to read/write from another device (like sensors, scales, ...), this may be a problem.